# Split multi-page tiff with pillow package

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, tiff

I have searched for that topic and I found the following code

```
from PIL import Image, ImageSequence

im = Image.open("MySample.tiff")
for i, page in enumerate(ImageSequence.Iterator(im)):
    page.save("Page_%d.png" % i)
```

The code works for some tiff files but I encountered an error with one of them
The traceback is like that

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-12bbb3a559f8> in <module>
      5 im = Image.open("MySample.tiff")
      6 for i, page in enumerate(ImageSequence.Iterator(im)):
----> 7     page.save("Page_%d.png" % i)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py in save(self, fp, format, **params)
   2128 
   2129         # may mutate self!
-> 2130         self._ensure_mutable()
   2131 
   2132         save_all = params.pop("save_all", False)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py in _ensure_mutable(self)
    617     def _ensure_mutable(self):
    618         if self.readonly:
--> 619             self._copy()
    620         else:
    621             self.load()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py in _copy(self)
    610 
    611     def _copy(self):
--> 612         self.load()
    613         self.im = self.im.copy()
    614         self.pyaccess = None

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py in load(self)
   1086     def load(self):
   1087         if self.tile and self.use_load_libtiff:
-> 1088             return self._load_libtiff()
   1089         return super().load()
   1090 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py in _load_libtiff(self)
   1190 
   1191         if err < 0:
-> 1192             raise OSError(err)
   1193 
   1194         return Image.Image.load(self)

OSError: -9
```

Comment: If you are having a problem with the Pillow fork of PIL, report it to [them](https://python-pillow.org/).

Comment: How about providing the tiff file in question here!?

Comment: I wish to share but this is personal. How can I send it to you?